# Finding starting and ending nodes of a street

Tags: google-maps, maps, here-api

I'm making an utility that allows street highlighting on mouseover, but so far I haven't managed to find the right approach.

Routing functions from Google and Here maps seem to be reliable in providing a path and visually showing it(making it work as a highlighting tool isn't an issue here). What I haven't managed to find yet is a way to determine where a street starts and ends, as in start and end "nodes". Searching through docs of both APIs hasn't brought me to anything.

Is it actually possible to find these nodes with these APIs? If not, are there any other mapping tools that provide that kind of information?

Answer (score 0):

There is straight solution provided by Here to give all the links (a street is made up of). However you can try to read the ROAD and Street related layers in Platform Data Extension(Fleet Telematics API). Refer to documentation in Here website:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/quick-start-view-map-data.html

Also take a look at the layers with their descriptions here (This is an official product link and all supported regions can only be requested live - they are not available in any document nor should be posted): https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layers?region=WEU&release=18148&url_root=pde.api.here.com

Comment: This straight solution you are talking about, I still haven't been able to find it. I can't seem to find any correlation between "links" and streets they belong to, nor any way to request a list of links that belong to a certain street. Could you perhaps guide me to the correct article?